# Streaming h.264 from UDP via Websocket and to the browser

Tags: javascript, websocket, udp, video-streaming, h.264

I am currently trying to stream some video in h264 format from udp to a video tag in the browser.
Currently nothing is showing on screen which means there is either an issue with the code or the video format/codec. There is no error message at all in the console

The current setup is this :

- PX4 Gazebo drone simulator running on Windows Subsystem for Linux. The simulator is streaming video via UDP in h.264 format - this is confirmed to be working by viewing the video in a real drone application (QGroundControl)
- UDP to Websocket bridge to forward the raw packets as is and unchanged to a Websocket server running in C#
- HTML page with a video tag and javascript to receive the packets and push them to the video tag - by using console.log, it is confirmed that the packets are being received fine and are in base64 format

The code for the page is :

```
<div>
    <h2>Video</h2>
    <video id="test-video" autoplay muted class="video-element"></video>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/microsoft-signalr/5.0.12/signalr.min.js"></script>

<script>
    const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl("/droneHub") 
        .build();

    connection.binaryType = 'arraybuffer';

    connection.start()
        .then(() => {
            console.log("Connected to SignalR hub");
            connection.invoke("JoinGroup", "drone253"); // get this from the current drone
        })
        .catch(err => console.error("Error connecting to SignalR hub:", err));

    // get video packets

    if ('MediaSource' in window) {
        let mediaSource = new MediaSource();
        
        let sourceBuffer;
        let bufferQueue = [];

        mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', function () {
            sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer('video/mp4; codecs="avc1.64001E,mp4a.40.2"');
        });

        document.getElementById('test-video').src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);

        connection.on("Video", function (dataChunk) {
            var byteArray = base64ToArrayBuffer(dataChunk);
            console.log(dataChunk);
            if (sourceBuffer && !sourceBuffer.updating) {
                sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(byteArray);
            }
        });
    } else {
        console.error('MSE not supported by this browser.');
    }

    function base64ToArrayBuffer(base64) {
        var binary_string = window.atob(base64);
        var len = binary_string.length;
        var bytes = new Uint8Array(len);
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            bytes[i] = binary_string.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        return bytes.buffer;
    }

</script>
```

I was expecting the video to play, but nothing shows on screen and no error message appear in the logs. I have tried changing the codecs in Javascript above but no success. I have also tried using video.js and jmuxer also without any joy.

The video is definitely displaying fine in QGroundControl

[QGroundControl camera feed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7l0XF.png)

[QGroundControl settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUga4.png)

I have also tried using FFMPEG and FFProbe to try and examine the stream and getting the error message below (the IP address is definitely correct)

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CH5qO.png)

Has anyone managed to get something like this working, or have any ideas how to get it working?

Comment: _"The packets are being received fine and are in base64 format"_ You need to first decode the packet **from Base64**. Decoding will give you (extract) the original video data per packet and then you can try feeding that into MediaSource. It should work if your data is correct (_eg:_ H264 video codec inside a fragmented MP4 container). Let us know what happens when you try to decode and play 3 packets in sequence (start with the very first received packet plus the next two packets)...

Comment: Thanks. I'm already decoding the Base64 packets here : 

```var byteArray = base64ToArrayBuffer(dataChunk);```

So I don't think this is the issue

Comment: **(1)** Next you need to `console.log( byteArray[0] );` ... Check array slots `[0]` then `[1]` then `[2]` and finally check `[3]`. If you got 4 numbers as: `0 0 0 1` then you have raw H.264 so it must first be put inside an MP4 container for playback to work... **(2)** If not getting `0 0 0 1` then, Check array slots `[4]` then `[5]` then `[6]` and finally check `[7]`. Does that give you 4 numbers as: `102 116 121 112`? If yes then you might have an MP4 after all (will advise how to fix) or else if not getting those 4 numbers then you possibly have some other non-browser compatible file type.

Comment: **PS:** Ty the modified version of your function's code. If the video still does not play then you can now also do the above mentioned checks: `console.log( byteArray[0] );` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this modified version of your `base64ToArrayBuffer` function...

```
function base64ToArrayBuffer(base64) 
{
    let binary_string = window.atob(base64);
    let len = ( binary_string.length / 2 );
    let bytes = new Uint8Array( len );
    
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) 
    {
        bytes[i] = parseInt( binary_string.substr(i*2, 2), 16 );
    }
    
    return bytes;
}
```

This should work (plays video) if the Base64 gives a correct Hex string (*eg:* correct string of binary values). A correct Hex string can *"divide by 2"* without leaving any remainders (no fractions).

It might not work (no playback) if the data is not in fragmented-MP4 format.

Comment: PS: Fixed small error in `.substr` code (it had wrong variable name).